# Generate database from model using MySQL as database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.Net MVC2.  I have a model with database design, and need to create a database from that model using MySQL as the back end.

I right-click on the model and select the `generate database from model` option, then I select MySQL as back end.

After that I can get a SQL query to execute. But when I execute the query, MS SQL Server is executing instead of MySQL.

Do you know how to make a database from the model using MySQL.

Comment: What are you using to auto generate the DB?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework 4.1 Code First?

Comment: @UpTheCreek-auto generate from model class in asp.net mvc2

Answer (score 0):

You can change the DDL generator under the properties of the Entity Model: `DDL Generation Template`.  I was able to switch this from `SSDLToMySQL.tt (VS)` to `SSDLToSQL10.tt (VS)`, which gave me the MySQL script.

(I'm assuming you already have the [MySQL connector for .NET](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) installed, right? )